# MacMini - what is the actual model of the CPU?

Tags: cpu, mac-mini

I am thinking of buying a couple of MacMinis for iPhone development.  I've looked at the specs for the computer on Apple's site, but it only lists the CPU as Core 2 Duo.  This does not help a lot as there are a dozen different models of that chip.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current Mac Mini uses a dual-core 64-bit "Penryn" Intel Core 2 Duo processor that runs at 2.4 or 2.66 GHz. Each CPU has a 3 MiB on-chip L2 cache that is shared between the two cores. Previous revisions used "Merom"-based Core 2 Duo and "Yonah"-based Core Duo and Solo chips.

While the Mac Mini G4 contained a separate graphics processor, all revisions of the Intel-based Mac Mini contain integrated GPUs. In Apple's early marketing of the Mac Mini G4, it touted the superiority of the use of a discrete ATI Radeon 9200 32 MiB graphics card over the integrated graphics included in many budget PCs.[27] The Intel GMA that was built into the Mac Mini was criticized for producing stuttering video, despite supporting hardware accelerated H.264 video playback, and disappointing frame rates in graphics-intensive 3D games.[28] However, the Nvidia GeForce 320M in the current model is considered the fastest integrated graphics processor on the market today, and touted by Apple to be twice as fast as the Nvidia GeForce 9400M used in previous models.